# How many elements of array are not null or empty?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I count number of elements in an array that are not null?

For this array I should get `3`:

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = 'foo';
$array[1] = '';
$array[2] = 'bar'; 
$array[3] = 'blabla';
```

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: null<>empty .correct your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_filter` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
count(array_filter($myarray))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
    if (!empty($v)) {
        $count++;
    }
}

echo $count; // 3 with your array
```